# how to parse data to android using flask framework in python

Tags: android, python, sql, google-maps, flask

hello i have this code in python

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():

    import mysql.connector

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                                  host='127.0.0.1', database='air_quality')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT coords.x,coords.y, pollution.* FROM coords ,pollution WHERE coords.id =pollution.id ")
    data=cursor.execute(query) 
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    tmp="test"
    for row in data:    
       tmp+="{''x'':''"+row[0] +"'',''y'':''"+row[1] +"'',''network'':''" +row[7] +"'',''country_code'':''" + row[3] +"',''pollutant'':''" +row[4] +"'',''numeric_val'':''" +row[5] +"'',''date'':''" +row[6] +"''}"
    return tmp    
app.run(threaded=True)
```

and i want to make an application with android studio using the data from my database to create markers on google maps according to my (x,y).how can i parse this data into android,as far i searched i only found using json format.Do i have to format the response into json ?and how can i do it? when i run my code  i get on my browser( http://127.0.0.1:5000/) my records!
sample:

```
test{''x'':''-13.860830000250354'',''y'':''28.498380000027481'',''network'':''CASA PALACIO-PUERTO DEL ROSARIO'',''country_code'':''ES',''pollutant'':''PM10'',''numeric_val'':''22'',''date'':''2015-10-17''}

{''x'':''-17.771554000133261'',''y'':''28.645396000388093'',''network'':''SAN ANTONIO-BRE?A BAJA'',''country_code'':''ES',''pollutant'':''PM10'',''numeric_val'':''16'',''date'':''2015-10-17''}
```